# Google map giving different distance than actual distance

Tags: php, google-maps

hello i am trying to integrate google map in to my application but since last 4 days i stick to only thing that when i enter long and latitude actual giving different result and my script giving diffrent distance.

i am showing my code here, can anybody please help me out for my custom function?

```
 function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
        var theta = lon1-lon2
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist)
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist;
    }



function find_nearest()
    {

        var max_dis = 791364782684;
        get_location();
        for ( var a in data['data'] )   
        {

            data['data'][a].distance = Math.sqrt (Math.pow(data['data'][a].latitude - lat,2) + Math.pow(data['data'][a].longitude - long,2) );

            if ( data['data'][a].distance < max_dis)
            {
                max_dis = data['data'][a].distance;
                data['avg_lat'] = data['data'][a].latitude;
                data['avg_lon'] = data['data'][a].longitude;
                data['nearest_key']=a;
            }
        }
        data['zoom']=15;


 function showDirection()
    {
        $("#errLbl").html('').hide();
        //                        alert($("#selected_postal").val())
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        directionsDisplay.setOptions({'suppressInfoWindows':true});   //to disable popup on google pin
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        //alert(document.getElementById('selected_panel').value)
        if(document.getElementById('selected_panel').value=='1'){
            var request = {
                origin: document.getElementById('address_from').value, 
                destination: document.getElementById('selected_postal').value,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('selected_panel').value=='2'){
            var request = {
                origin: document.getElementById('selected_postal').value, 
                destination: document.getElementById('address_to').value,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
        }
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                $("#errLbl").html('').hide();
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
            else{
                $("#errLbl").html('Address is not recognized.</br>Please try again.');
            }
        });
        //            if($("#errLbl").html()!='')
        $("#errLbl").show();
    }
```

Comment: You are computing "as a bird flies" distance, Google is computing "as a car drives" distance

Comment: means? i am not getting how to change that view?

Comment: Your computation is a straight line from point A to point B, Google computes the driving distance which is not a straight line there for your numbers will not match.

Comment: so which code line i need to change in my function?

Comment: There isn't a line of code you can change to make your numbers match

Comment: i still not getting you i stuck since 4 days and i frustrate a lot. can you please elaborate in detail.?

Comment: use Google map api for exact same results, see below:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Answer (score 2):

You are computing "as a bird flies" distance [The Red Line], Google is computing "as a car drives" distance [The Blue Line].

There is not a formula you can apply to your function to recreate what Google is doing, there for your numbers will never match.

[image: as a bird flies vs. as a car drives]